# sorting a list name and date using comparator

Tags: java, list, sorting, comparator

I am trying to implement custom sorting using comparator. So far I was able to sort a list in an order where specified name on the top of the list and the rest follows.

**Code:**

```
public class SortingTest implements Comparator<SortingTest> {
 String name;
 Date date;

 public SortingTest(String name, Date date) {
    this.name = name;
    this.date = date;
 }

@Override
public int compare(SortingTest o1, SortingTest o2) {
    if (this.name.equals(o2.name)) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<SortingTest> list = new ArrayList<SortingTest>();
    Calendar cl = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date d = cl.getTime();
    SortingTest s1 = new SortingTest("Sas", d);
    cl.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    Date d1 = cl.getTime();
    SortingTest s2 = new SortingTest("Dave", d1);
    cl.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    Date d2 = cl.getTime();
    SortingTest s3 = new SortingTest("Jabir", d2);
    cl.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    Date d4 = cl.getTime();
    SortingTest s5 = new SortingTest("Meina", d4);
    cl.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    Date d5 = cl.getTime();
    SortingTest s6 = new SortingTest("Sas", d5);
    list.add(s1);
    list.add(s2);
    list.add(s3);
    list.add(s5);
    list.add(s6);

    Collections.sort(list, s1);

    System.out.println("After sorting");
    for (SortingTest st : list) {
        System.out.println(st.name);
    }
}
}
```

**Current code Output:**

```
Sas
Sas
Dave
Jabir
Meina
```

But I would like to sort the list first by name and then by date. So the output should be:

```
Sas, 8/6/2015
Sas, 14/6/2015
Dave, 8/6/2015
Jabir, 10/6/2015
Meina, 11/6/205
```

**Updated 1:**

My criteria is that I should be able to pass any name (in this case "sas"/ s1) and sort the list so that the passed name should be on top of the list and then the rest. So in the above example I have passed an object s1 to collection.sort method. s1 holds the name "sas" and in compare method I am checking if any other element in the list has name "sas" then give value 1 (top of the list) or 0 if it's not.

Comment: current code output??? you sure that is the output you got? Also your expected result is not sorted.

Comment: if names are equal, then compare by date

Comment: If you sort by name first, shouldn't "Dave"` be ahead of "Sas"?

Comment: should you be comparing o1 and o2 not this and o2?

Comment: I have passed an object s1 to collection.sort method. s1 holds the name "sas" and in compare method I am checking if any other element in the list has name "sas" then give value 1 (top of the list) or 0 if it's not. I also updated the post to be more clear. Thanks

Comment: @ScaryWombat That would work if the OP was implementation `Comparable` instead of `Comparator`, as they pass a reference to `s1` to the `Collections.sort` method, it would mean you would constantly comparing `s1` to all the other values, which I doubt is what you would want to do...

Comment: @dasblinkenlight The sorting is done in reverse order...poorly, but that's how it's done, check the `compare` method implementation...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you could implement `Comparable` instead of `Comparator` and it would allow you to use `Collections.sort(list)` instead of `Collections.sort(list, s1)`.

Now, personally, I don't like changing the core "comparable" requirements of object, as they may have been defined that way for a reason, instead, I like to create `Comparator` based on the immediate needs instead, for example..

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<SortingTest>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(SortingTest o1, SortingTest o2) {
        int result = o1.name.compareTo(o2.name);
        if (result == 0) {
            result = o1.date.compareTo(o2.date);
        } else {
            result = -result;
        }
        return result;
    }
});
```

This basically compares the name of each `SortingTest` instance, if they are `0`, it will then use the `Date` to determine the difference.

This would then output something like...

```
Sas Thu Aug 07 12:30:11 EST 2014
Sas Mon Aug 11 12:30:11 EST 2014
Meina Sun Aug 10 12:30:11 EST 2014
Jabir Sat Aug 09 12:30:11 EST 2014
Dave Fri Aug 08 12:30:11 EST 2014
```

Comment: My criteria is that I should be able to pass any name (in this case "sas"/ s1) and sort the list so that the passed name should be on top of the list and then the rest. I got the idea of how ur sorting the date, I can use this logic to sort name and date. Thanks for the help.. :)

Comment: I wouldn't use `Comparator` directly in this way, what I would do is devise a custom `Comparator` that took a `String` (name) when when it found that (`name.equals(o.name)`) it would give that object precedence, but that's just me ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer can you please add some code how you we can do this in Java 8?

Comment: @KickButtowski You can use it just the way it is in Java 8 ;) - Just because there's a "feature" doesn't mean you need to run out and use.  Not everyone is using 8 and Lambda functions are not backwards compatible...

Comment: @MadProgrammer really? I think it is more compact than what you said

Comment: @KickButtowski I also think it's harder to read as it hides the underlying contractual requirements...the way it's written here is obvious exactly what is need, but that's just me ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer I see what you mean, that would be a much cleaner code. I will def gonna refactor the code in that way. Thanks for the advise.

Comment: @MadProgrammer why I got this? After sorting
Sas Wed Aug 06 20:17:51 PDT 2014
Dave Thu Aug 07 20:17:51 PDT 2014
Jabir Fri Aug 08 20:17:51 PDT 2014
Meina Sat Aug 09 20:17:51 PDT 2014
Sas Sun Aug 10 20:17:51 PDT 2014

Comment: @KickButtowski No idea, what did you change...?  The code I produced printed the list that is in the post...

Comment: @MadProgrammer nothing wrong with your code. i jsut try to understand java 8. i did this.  Collections.sort(list, (SortingTest dt1, SortingTest dt2) -> dt1.date.compareTo(dt2.date)); it must work . am I right?

Comment: @KickButtowski Oh, okay, yes, but you change the comparision, your list is now in `Date` only order which is correct, `Aug 6, Aug 7, Aug 8, Aug 9, Aug 10`...which is correct for what you've done ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer what you mean? it must be ordered by date ? so how can i change what I want to satisfy what op wants?

Comment: @KickButtowski It needs to sorted by name first, then by `Date`...You're output is correct for sorting by `Date` only...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58841/discussion-between-kick-buttowski-and-madprogrammer).

Comment: @MadProgrammer could you please come to chat for a sec plz?